# Update the column value of the first row given a filter criteria by column in R

Tags: r, dataframe, row

I have a complex question whose answer is not anywhere.

Suppose that I have the following dataframe:

```
   individual      gen_check    acc       loss
1  nnn/nn/nn/nn    2            0.9889    0.0112
2  nnn/n/nn        2            0.7845    0.3451
3  nnn/nn/nn/nn    2            0.564     0.4231
```

What I want to do is to update the gen_check value of the first row when I filter by individual = "nnn/nn/nn/nn" and gen_check = 2, and I want to update the gen_check value to 3.

I've tried the following expression but it modifies me both first and third columns, but I want to update the first one.

```
fitness_calculations <- within(fitness_calculations, gen_check[individual == "nnn/nn/nn/nn" & gen_check == 2] <- 3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We create the index along with the condition whether it is `duplicated`

```
i1 <- with(fitness_calculations, individual == "nnn/nn/nn/nn" & gen_check ==  2)
i2 <- !duplicated(i1) & i1

fitness_calculations$gen_check[i2] <- 3
fitness_calculations
#    individual gen_check    acc   loss
#1 nnn/nn/nn/nn         3 0.9889 0.0112
#2     nnn/n/nn         2 0.7845 0.3451
#3 nnn/nn/nn/nn         2 0.5640 0.4231
```

---

Or another option is to wrap with `which` and extract only the first index

```
i2 <- which(i1)[1]
fitness_calculations$gen_check[i2] <- 3
```

#### data

```
fitness_calculations <- structure(list(individual = c("nnn/nn/nn/nn",
 "nnn/n/nn", "nnn/nn/nn/nn"
 ), gen_check = c(2L, 2L, 2L), acc = c(0.9889, 0.7845, 0.564), 
loss = c(0.0112, 0.3451, 0.4231)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
 "2", "3"))
```

Comment: So this index contains the first row that "fix" the criteria?

Comment: @CarlosVázquezLosada  You can wrap with `which` and select the first index or create a logical index with `duplicated`

Comment: So I suppose that this works too even if the result contiains just 1 row, right?

Comment: @CarlosVázquezLosada  Yes, it should work if there is atleast one row.  If it is all FALSE, the assignment using first will not change any value, but with `which` it will have a `NA` i.e `which(c(FALSE, FALSE))[1]#
[1] NA`